# How does company mode work?

Tags: completion, company-mode, ide

I am trying to set up a quasi-IDE experience on Emacs for C/++, and I installed the `company` package. However, it seems it doesn't work. For what I undersood, `company` by itself is only the front-end. Freshly installed, it only does basic completion (i.e., the words you alredy typed), and it doesn't show completions without a back-end a, for example, `irony`. Is it right?

I have Emacs 26, and I have already installed `clang` (not `libclang`), but it seems it doesn't help. Can someone of you explain how does the company autocompletion works?

Comment: Far too broad. This site is for specific questions, typically how-to. Perhaps try a discussion site, such as Reddit, or the Emacs help mailing list, help-gnu-emacs@gnu.org.

Answer (score 2):

Look into lsp  or eglot. They provide completion candidates for company.

Personally, I used eglot now with vertico completion and it "just works" since i plumbs iself into completion-at-point functions.

https://github.com/joaotavora/eglot